# What is the best way to calculate centralities for a single node in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, sna, node-centrality

I am able to calculate different kinds of centralities such as *degree*, *betweenness*, *closeness*, and *eigenvector* for all the nodes in **graph G**. For instance, this code calculates the *betweenness centrality* for all of the included nodes of **graph G**:

```
import networkx as nx
# build up a graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B','C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E')])
bw_centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True)
print (bw_centrality)
```

For *large networks*, it is very time consuming to calculate some of the centralities, such as *betweenness* and *closeness*. Therefore, I would like to calculate the centrality of **only a subset of nodes**, instead of calculating **all of the nodes' centrality**. In the example above, how can I calculate the *betweenness* of **node A**, by **Networkx** library in **Python**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a graph, I found a solution for calculating the closeness centrality of a single node. But, for betweenness, I have not been able to find a solution. Let's calculate a node's closeness centrality in a graph. Here is how the closeness of all the nodes can be calculated:
import networkx as nx

```
# build up a graph

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B','C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E')])
cc_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G)

print (cc_centrality )
```

Therefore, the above code produces the following result:

```
{'A': 0.4, 'B': 0.5714285714285714, 'C': 0.6666666666666666, 'D': 0.5714285714285714, 'E': 0.4}
```

In the next step, we will calculate **the closeness of node A separately**. According to the source code for *Neworkx*, *closeness centrality* has the following meaning:

```
closeness_centrality(G, u=None, distance=None, wf_improved=True)
```

The *graph G* shows the defined graph, and `u` represents **the node you want to determine its closeness separately**. To calculate the *closeness of node A*, follow these steps:

```
nx.closeness_centrality(G, u='A')
```

The result equals to `0.4`. Similarly, `nx.closeness_centrality(G, u='B')` gives you `0.5714285714285714`.

Answer (score 0):

*Networkx* has introduced a new form of centrality, called **Group Centrality**, which calculates the centrality of a group of nodes. To illustrate, if you want to calculate a centrality of 3 nodes in *Networkx*, the introduced capability will calculate the desired centrality of those 3 nodes and give you a number (just one number), indicating the *combined centrality of 3 nodes*. In order to calculate the centrality of a node, it should be viewed as a group. Therefore, its centrality can be calculated separately. Based on the above question, we can calculate the betweenness centrality of all nodes as follows:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B','C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E')])
bw_centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True)
print (bw_centrality)
```

The code above produces the following result:

```
{'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.6666666666666666, 'D': 0.5, 'E': 0.0}
```

Now, we use the **group centrality** feature to calculate node *C*'s centrality, as follows:

```
nx.group_betweenness_centrality(G, ['C'])
```

The result of calculating the `betweenness` of node `C` equals to `0.6666666666666666`. Visit the following link for more information:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html